# How do you avoid collision in Hash if a malicious hacker is trying to force collisions on Hash key?

Tags: data-structures, hash

Recently in one of the interviews, I was asked following,

> We have our own hash implementation. Let's say we open source our Hash implementation where the logic of generating hashcode is visible. Now, a hacker can force collision as he can send same key with different values. What can be done to prevent such scenario?

I was stuck, I tried to discussing following,

- On hash function to be universal hash function like `(ax + b) mod p` where `a`, `b` and `p` are big primes hidden in environment variable, which can reduce the probability of collision. But they argued that as software is open source, we can't hide it. (bad coding pattern, but still for sake of argument it is valid).
- I even even suggested, Hash pointing to another hash if we see too many collisions. But it is just delaying the eventuality of multiple collisions in the next hash.
- Block DDos attack from hacker

But none of the answers seemed to satisfy the interviewer. Now, I'm confused and want to know. What are the other ways to handle forceable collisions in `Hash`?

Comment: Didn't they just want to hear salt?

Comment: But if hacker knows salt value then you can still make collisions happen, right? We can't use random salt, otherwise we will not be able retrieve hash values.

Comment: They could be pushing you to analyze the problem and understand its limitations. i.e. if the algorithm is known and the primes are known, the collisions need to be prevented by other means (e.g. preemptively detecting attempts for collisions) It was not your answer that mattered, rather your ability to analyze the problem

Comment: @EriksKlotins oh..ok. But how can we preemptively detecting attempts for collisions?